# Searching on an autocomplete map does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing the autocomplete of the Google Maps API, so that it looks inside a polygon of coordinates for the address and validates that it is inside it.

The problem is that it works, until I enter the address (as an example) of "San Juan 2638", and **if I select it by clicking on the suggestions**, the result is a map search in the United States, when it should be in Rosario, Argentina.

I hope you can help me, because I can not find the error

I leave you the complete code of what I am doing

**JS:**

```
    /*=============================================
    GOOGLE AUTOCOMPLETE + MAP
    =============================================*/

    function initAutocomplete() {

        var pac_input = document.getElementById('registroDireccion');

        var autocomplete_options = {
                         types: ['address'],
                         componentRestrictions: {country: "ar"}
        };

        /*=============================================
        SELECTION OF FIRST SUGGESTION WHEN GIVING "ENTER"
        =============================================*/

        (function pacSelectFirst(input) {
            // store the original event binding function
            var _addEventListener = (input.addEventListener) ? input.addEventListener : input.attachEvent;

            function addEventListenerWrapper(type, listener) {
                // Simulate a 'down arrow' keypress on hitting 'return' when no pac suggestion is selected,
                // and then trigger the original listener.
                if (type == "keydown") {
                    var orig_listener = listener;
                    listener = function(event) {
                        var suggestion_selected = $(".pac-item-selected").length > 0;
                        if (event.which == 13 && !suggestion_selected) {
                            var simulated_downarrow = $.Event("keydown", {
                                keyCode: 40,
                                which: 40
                            });
                            orig_listener.apply(input, [simulated_downarrow]);
                        }

                        orig_listener.apply(input, [event]);
                    };
                }

                _addEventListener.apply(input, [type, listener]);
            }

            input.addEventListener = addEventListenerWrapper;
            input.attachEvent = addEventListenerWrapper;

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocomplete_options);

        })(pac_input);

        //var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

            /*=============================================
            VALIDATE ADDRESS WITHIN THE COORDINATE POLYGON
            =============================================*/

            // We create the instace bounds
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            // We extract the coordinates
            var coords = [

                    {"lat": -32.9524231, "lng": -60.6682936},{"lat": -32.9719713, "lng": -60.67327},{"lat": -32.9741199, "lng": -60.6609489},{"lat": -32.9672002, "lng": -60.6591224},{"lat": -32.9717621, "lng": -60.6342073},{"lat": -32.9694741, "lng": -60.6335479},{"lat": -32.9715067, "lng": -60.6218164},{"lat": -32.9680472, "lng": -60.6205835},{"lat": -32.9630917, "lng": -60.6216094},{"lat": -32.958511, "lng": -60.6209314},{"lat": -32.9521298, "lng": -60.624212},{"lat": -32.9520442, "lng": -60.6251776},{"lat": -32.9503966, "lng": -60.6262076},{"lat": -32.9501265, "lng": -60.6256068},{"lat": -32.9462216, "lng": -60.6283345},{"lat": -32.9380717, "lng": -60.636903},{"lat": -32.9317529, "lng": -60.6468345},{"lat": -32.9265583, "lng": -60.6577651},{"lat": -32.9176559, "lng": -60.6700872},{"lat": -32.9182323, "lng": -60.6901178},{"lat": -32.9197859, "lng": -60.6891415},{"lat": -32.9284696, "lng": -60.6885702},{"lat": -32.9282011, "lng": -60.6780258},{"lat": -32.9294789, "lng": -60.6778898},{"lat": -32.9294001, "lng": -60.6743024},{"lat": -32.9333037, "lng": -60.6713756},{"lat": -32.9334751, "lng": -60.6734615},{"lat": -32.9351777, "lng": -60.6738827},{"lat": -32.9344493, "lng": -60.677983},{"lat": -32.9377555, "lng": -60.6788352},{"lat": -32.9360567, "lng": -60.6882969},{"lat": -32.9374164, "lng": -60.6886667},{"lat": -32.9364591, "lng": -60.6936267},{"lat": -32.9405789, "lng": -60.6936545},{"lat": -32.9481519, "lng": -60.6934212}

                ] 

            // We add the coordinate to the bounds
            .map(function(coord) {

                bounds.extend(coord);
                return coord;

            });

            // We create the polygon
            var area = new google.maps.Polygon({

                paths: coords,
                strokeColor: '#F99830',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#F99830',
                fillOpacity: 0.30,
                draggable: false

            });

            // We created the map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

                zoom: 12.6,
                center: bounds.getCenter(), // Centramos el mapa al area
                mapTypeId: 'terrain',
                disableDefaultUI: true

            });

            // We add the area to the map
            area.setMap(map);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                $('#registroDireccion').on('change', function() {
                    var place = $(this).val().trim();
                    if (!place) {
                        return;
                    }
                    geocoder.geocode({
                            address: place
                        },
                        function(results, status) {

                            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                var result = results[0];
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: result.geometry.location,
                                    map: map,
                                    label: place
                                });

                                if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(result.geometry.location, area)) {

                            $("#registroDireccion").parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>GREAT!</strong> Our delivery system arrives at your address.</div>');

                            } else {

                                $("#registroDireccion").parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>WHAT EVIL!</Strong> Our delivery system does NOT arrive at your address.</div>');

                                    document.getElementById("registroDireccion").value = "";

                                }

                            }

                        });

                })

            });

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">


                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroDireccion" name="registroDireccion" placeholder="Dirección de envío" required>

                    </div>

</div>

<div>

        <button type="button" id="mostrarMapa" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-left">Mostrar zona de envío</button>

</div>

                <div class="col-sm-12" id="map"></div>
```

**SCRIPT API GOOGLE:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?library=geometry&key=AIzaSyBDJVJOqxxr1PfcuzMZWYOut0lkGDW1YsU&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Did you not read the docs? [Everything is explained there](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area). I don't see that you are applying your bounds to the Autocomplete.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes I have readed it. And if you look at the code, the limits are set. The problem here is that the search is not correct when the suggestion is selected with the mouse click. In the example, if I look for "San Juan 2638" and I click on the suggestion of "San Juan 2638, Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina", it takes me to the United States. And if I do the same but with the enter key, search correctly.

Comment: Well I must be blind then. Would you point me to the line where you set the Polygon bounds to the autocomplete?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Before creating the polygon, I am adding the coordinates to the bounds. Then, I create the map with those bounds. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: There is an answer below in case you didn't see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is not minimal... And I can't see where you set your bounds to the Autocomplete, which you should do, if you expect to see suggestions from only this area.

Below is an example of how to implement it the right way.

1. Create the bounds object from your coordinates
2. Apply the bounds object to the Autocomplete and restrict the search to this area by using `strictBounds: true`
3. Try it, as you suggested in your question (Enter `San Juan 2638` and click on the suggestion)
4. It creates a Marker and pans the map to the location, which is in Rosario, AR

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  // We create the instace bounds
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // We extract the coordinates
  var coords = [

      {
        "lat": -32.9524231,
        "lng": -60.6682936
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9719713,
        "lng": -60.67327
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9741199,
        "lng": -60.6609489
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9672002,
        "lng": -60.6591224
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9717621,
        "lng": -60.6342073
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9694741,
        "lng": -60.6335479
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9715067,
        "lng": -60.6218164
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9680472,
        "lng": -60.6205835
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9630917,
        "lng": -60.6216094
      }, {
        "lat": -32.958511,
        "lng": -60.6209314
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9521298,
        "lng": -60.624212
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9520442,
        "lng": -60.6251776
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9503966,
        "lng": -60.6262076
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9501265,
        "lng": -60.6256068
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9462216,
        "lng": -60.6283345
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9380717,
        "lng": -60.636903
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9317529,
        "lng": -60.6468345
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9265583,
        "lng": -60.6577651
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9176559,
        "lng": -60.6700872
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9182323,
        "lng": -60.6901178
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9197859,
        "lng": -60.6891415
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9284696,
        "lng": -60.6885702
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9282011,
        "lng": -60.6780258
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9294789,
        "lng": -60.6778898
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9294001,
        "lng": -60.6743024
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9333037,
        "lng": -60.6713756
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9334751,
        "lng": -60.6734615
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9351777,
        "lng": -60.6738827
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9344493,
        "lng": -60.677983
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9377555,
        "lng": -60.6788352
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9360567,
        "lng": -60.6882969
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9374164,
        "lng": -60.6886667
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9364591,
        "lng": -60.6936267
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9405789,
        "lng": -60.6936545
      }, {
        "lat": -32.9481519,
        "lng": -60.6934212
      }
    ]

    // We add the coordinate to the bounds
    .map(function(coord) {

      bounds.extend(coord);
      return coord;
    });

  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode'],
      bounds: bounds,
      strictBounds: true
    });

  ac.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    var place = ac.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: place.geometry.location,
      map: map
    });

    map.panTo(place.geometry.location);

    var html = '<div>Latitude: ' + place.geometry.location.lat() + '</div>';
    html += '<div>Longitude: ' + place.geometry.location.lng() + '</div>';

    document.getElementById('geometry').innerHTML = html;
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
}

#geometry {
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: yellowgreen;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
<div id="geometry">

</div>
<div id="map-canvas">

</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

> You might need to use a valid API key to get rid of warnings and get the expected results.